# React no acepta CSS específico de los navegadores

Tags: css3, reactjs

Todo el CSS que sea especifico de un navegador, lo ignora, no aparecen warnings y en el CSS de la pagina web no esta.

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
-webkit-box-pack: justify;
-ms-flex-pack: justify;
justify-content: space-between;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Comment: Importas tú css en el javascript? O  tienes los estilos como objeto javascript?

Comment: Estan importados, ya no estoy con este proyecto pero me gustaría saber el motivo, pienso que seguramente sea por el webpack por defecto de react-script.